# How to use cscope with paths that contain spaces

Tags: vim, cscope

There are some folder that contains space, and as a result, those folders can not be indexed using cscope.

Can i ask you for help to solve this,or any suggestion.

thanks
Julius

---

Thanks for your reply.

My steps to use cscope like the following

- find . -name '*.scala'>cscope.files
- cscope -b
  at this step. i see the message indicates that can not find file:
  cscope: cannot find file /work/project/copy 
  cscope: cannot find file of 
  cscope: cannot find file  fp/src/main/jav.... 
  Actually copy of fp is a folder.so i think cscope can  not recognize the folder contains space.

I encountered this problem when i tried to use vim with cscope.maybe i need move this question to other tag.

Comment: You used the Vim tag.  Is this because you are trying to use the `:cscope` commands within Vim?  If so, can you show the commands that you are trying and what errors you are getting?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it simply using GNU find at least, you can use the `-printf` or `-fprintf` options for that:

```
find . -type f -fprintf cscope.files '"%p"\n'
```

Comment: simplify %h/%f to %p

Comment: Yours is the fastest answer: 8% faster than mine, 14% faster than with sed . . . and 1000x as fast as with exec!

Answer (score 4):

pydave's answer is very slow. This way took 0.10s where pydave's answer took 14s:

```
find . -name "*.scala" | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' > cscope.files
```

Comment: Kudos! Works really fast

Answer (score 2):

You can use find's -exec to force quotes around your output:

```
find . -name "*.scala" -exec echo \"{}\" \; > cscope.files
```

You might need to mess around with quoting/escaping if you're doing this from a script.

Comment: This answer takes ~1 second to do ~100 files. My answer takes ~1 second to do ~100,000 files.

Comment: @webb: Using fprintf (Olivier Diotte's answer) certainly seems like a better use of `find` than my naive proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Double quoting the files names works in cygwin, where as escaping with backslash does not.

```
$ find $PWD -name "*.scala" | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' > cscope.files
```

Comment: sed 's/.*/"&"/' is slightly faster